# Is there a way to highlight/conduct on topic discussion in a question?

Tags: migration, discussion

Say one were to ask a question and the answer were to spark a difference of opinion that turns into something very educational.  Is there either a way to make sure that all the comments come up on load (not hidden after 3 or 4 comments) or another place to migrate the discussion in order continue it?

After further consideration, I have decided to request such a feature.  Certainly one that loads pages with all comments expanded if one would so choose, and perhaps one where the OP can force a comment thread to be expanded in order to highlight which areas they find most helpful.  I believe that such a feature requires a little refinement before it is properly considered

Comment: The problem is that SO is not a discussion site, so any suggestion for a feature that would encourage such discussion would be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Chat sites (where this sort of thing can happen) for each site are in the process of being launched which will take the following format.

> stackoverflow.com
> meta.stackoverflow.com
> chat.stackoverflow.com

Currently in beta.

[Source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/third-place-chat-beta-preview/)

Answer (score 0):

*Is there either a way to make sure that all the comments come up on load (not hidden after 3 or 4 comments)*
@: Currently, I doubt so. Are you requesting this feature?

*another place to migrate the discussion in order continue it?*
@: I'm assuming you are refering to SO site. If the thread should be in another site e.g. meta or SU, it will be migrated. If it remains where it is, I don't see any reason to move it.